# Connect Error (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, rhel

I am migrating a website apache/php/mysql to a newer server. I created a database dump and imported it, migrated php, html files over, imported database and set password, although it is a different one than the original server. Both mysql and apache are running, but if I pull up the website all I see is "Connect Error (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

I have also tried to change the mysql password back to the original one on the old server, but than I no longer see that error or the website. This is on a rhel 8 server.

Comment: FYI your website should NOT be logging into the database as root (the system administrator), that's a big security risk. Create an account in mysql especially for the application and give it only the permissions it actually needs

Comment: have you migrated the user from the old database to new one or only data has been migrated, you need to migrate the mysql.user table or import MySQL table to the target server